# Getting updated entity object type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

it's been days I'm smashing my head against this problem.
I've got a wpf application using a service based database interacting through EF6.

I want to detect which entity type has been updated so I can update only its relative datagrid
the DBContext looks like this now

```
    public partial class DataEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DataEntities()
            : base("name=DataEntities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Anni> Anni { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Classi> Classi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ClassiConcorso> ClassiConcorso { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Discipline> Discipline { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Docenti> Docenti { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Indirizzi> Indirizzi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Sedi> Sedi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SistemaOrario> SistemaOrario { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VisualizzaClassi> VisualizzaClassi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VisualizzaDocenti> VisualizzaDocenti { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VisualizzaSistemaOrario> VisualizzaSistemaOrario { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VisualizzaTotaleOre> VisualizzaTotaleOre { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VisualizzaTotaleOrePerClasseConcorso> VisualizzaTotaleOrePerClasseConcorso { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler SavingMultipleChanges;
        public event EventHandler SavingAnniChanges;
        public event EventHandler SavingClassiChanges;
        public event EventHandler SavingClassiConcorsoChanges;
        public event EventHandler SavingDisciplineChanges;
        public event EventHandler SavingDocentiChanges;
        public event EventHandler SavingIndirizziChanges;
        public event EventHandler SavingSediChanges;
        public event EventHandler SavingSistemaOrarioChanges;

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            // Notify objects that want to know, that we are gonna save some stuff
            IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> changes = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(t => t.State != EntityState.Unchanged);
            if (changes.Count() == 1)
            {
                var change = changes.ElementAt(0);
                if (change.Entity.GetType() == Anni.Create().GetType())
                {
                    SavingAnniChanges.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }
                if (change.Entity.GetType() == Sedi.Create().GetType())
                {
                    SavingClassiChanges.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }
                if (change.Entity.GetType() == ClassiConcorso.Create().GetType())
                {
                    SavingClassiConcorsoChanges.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }
                if (change.Entity.GetType() == Discipline.Create().GetType())
                {
                    SavingDisciplineChanges.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }
                if (change.Entity.GetType() == Docenti.Create().GetType())
                {
                    SavingDocentiChanges.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }
                if (change.Entity.GetType() == Indirizzi.Create().GetType())
                {
                    SavingIndirizziChanges.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }
                if (change.Entity.GetType() == Sedi.Create().GetType())
                {
                    SavingSediChanges.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }
                if (change.Entity.GetType() == SistemaOrario.Create().GetType())
                {
                    SavingSistemaOrarioChanges.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SavingMultipleChanges.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
            }

            // Call the actual SaveChanges method to apply the changes to the database
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

So this works, is there any fancier way to do it?

Note this is version 0, next will be a single event passing the types through EventArgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible via reflection, but you need to make sure every event name matches single pattern

```
var change = changes.ElementAt(0);

var entityType = change.Entity.GetType();
var eventDelegate = (Delegate)GetType()
    .GetField("Saving" + entityType.Name + "Changes", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetValue(this);

if (eventDelegate != null)
{
    eventDelegate.DynamicInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
else 
{
    throw new NotImplementedException("Event handler not implemented for type " + entityType.Name);
}
```

Later on you could create some generic event handler args to pass to your events

```
public class GenericEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
```

And code to create instance

```
var eventArgsType = typeof(GenericEventArgs<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
var eventArgs = Activator.CreateInstance(eventArgsType);
eventArgsType.GetProperty("Item").SetValue(eventArgs, change);
```

Comment: It gives me a null reference error on the line
eventHandler.GetRaiseMethod().Invoke(this, new object[] { new EventArgs() });

Comment: @DanielMartin fixed it, please check

Comment: Ok thanks, do you perhaps know how to bind wpf datagrid to a DBSet hiding some fields?
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64512341/binding-ef-dbsett-to-a-wpf-datagrid)
It works perfectly what you said